# Snowflake - CREATE STAGE - Pattern for dynamic url with Azure

Tags: azure, url, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, stage

I would like to specify a dynamic url for a stage but * doesn't work. Is there some way to do it ?

I would like to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE MY_STAGE
  url                   = 'azure://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfolder/*/myparquet'  
  credentials           = ...
  file_format           = (type = 'parquet')
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this in a stage, but you can do it in your copy statements.

so you can set up your stage like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE MY_STAGE
  url                   = 'azure://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfolder/'  
  credentials           = ...
  file_format           = (type = 'parquet')
;
```

and then use a copy into statement that looks something like this:

```
copy into mytable
from @MY_STAGE
  pattern='.*/myparquet';
```

See [Copy into documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-using-pattern-matching).